# Importing statsmodels in RHEL fails with undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeUTF8

Tags: statsmodels

I installed statsmodels and all its dependencies on RHEL. While importing statsmodels, it gives me:

> (,
>   ImportError('/home/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/kalmanf/kalman_loglike.so:
>   undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeUTF8',))

Looking at other pages, I re-compiled python 2.7.15 (that I have), with UCS-4 as unicode representation. But then, numpy complains that it is looking for UCS-2! So, statsmodels needs UCS-4, but its dependency, numpy, needs UCS-2.

Any suggestions to come out of this? I am actually struggling from last 1 week on this. Looks like a bug in statsmodels, but then it works fine with Anaconda on Windows. So, it appears only in RHEL machine.

Answer (score 0):

After updating pyconfig-64.h in python-dev include as below:

```
/* Define as the size of the unicode type. */
//#define Py_UNICODE_SIZE 4
#define Py_UNICODE_SIZE 2
```

I found that unicodeobject.h :

```
/* FIXME: MvL's new implementation assumes that Py_UNICODE_SIZE is
   properly set, but the default rules below doesn't set it.  I'll
   sort this out some other day -- fredrik@pythonware.com */
```

After aligning these files in python-dev to reflect UCS2, re-compiling python for UCS2, AND updating around 17 different .c files in statsmodels like:

```
//  #define __Pyx_PyUnicode_READ_CHAR(u, i) ((Py_UCS4) (PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(u)[i]))
#define __Pyx_PyUnicode_READ_CHAR(u, i) ((Py_UCS2)(PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(u)[i]))
```

I finally managed to import statsmodels as well as numpy successfully.

I think this needs to be fixed in python as well as statsmodels.